# Find and fix wrong values in a simple, linear data set

Tags: algorithm, error-correction

This is probably a simple question yet I could not find a good approach.

I've got a limited number of ordered int values that are supposed to be of similar distance to each other, e.g: `32, 42, 52, 62, 72, 82`.

In reality though, some values are wrong. We might end up with `32, 51, 62, 66, 71, 83`.

How can I find the obviously wrong value (in this case: 66) and move it to the correct position (42)?

- It can be assumed that most data are still valid so it is still possible to calculate a good guess of the correct distance between points (here: 10).
- The number of points is known and correct (i.e., we just need to move but not add or remove points).
- The data boundaries to the left and to the right are unknown, behavior in edge cases can be defined freely.

---

While writing the question I thought of something. An idea might be to extract a function `f(x) = a + x * b` (that's easy) and iterate over the known number of points. The datum with the largest distance to an iterated point is removed and inserted at the iterated position which has the largest distance to an original point.

Comment: You said that "some values are wrong." Is that over multiple sets? I.e. is it safe to assume that there is exactly one wrong value in any given set? (And +1 for knowing that "data" is plural!)

Comment: Does "similar distance to each other" mean, that e.g. the sequence 32, 42, 51, 61, 71, 83 is corrected to 32, 42, 52, 62, 72, 82 (suppose we know the correct distance is 10)?

Comment: @LordTorgamus: It is unknown if/how many wrong values there are.

Comment: @ChristianAmmer: Correcting those minor inconsistencies is not necessary. In fact is is preferable to leave them as is. Only major mistakes (like >30% deviation) need to be fixed.

Answer (score 1):

You can use [robust regression](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Robust_regression), which is nothing more than a fancy term for "fitting a straight line to a bunch of points in such a way that points that don't fit well are gracefully removed".

If you don't want to write the non-linear optimization code, you can use [iteratively reweighted least squares](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Iteratively_reweighted_least_squares) to leverage any existing weighted linear regression code you have lying around.

The idea is that you do [weighted least squares](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Weighted_least_squares#Weighted_least_squares) to fit a straight line to your points. You then assign a weighting to each point that measures whether you think it's an [outlier](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Outlier), deviating from the regression line too much (eg. via the [Huber loss function](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Huber_loss_function)). You then redo the regression with the weights. You'll get a new line and therefore can compute a new set of weights. Repeat until convergence (or a max number of iterations). You'll be left with weights that tell you which points are bad, and a line that nicely fits the remaining points and which can be used to replace the outliers.

I think the implementation isn't vastly longer than the text description above.

Comment: I thought of regression too, its idea seems fitting, but I don't see how to create a line out of the given data. Could you explain that?

Answer (score 0):

If only one datum is wrong, and assuming increasing values (as in your example):
The data goes in DATA and DATA_SIZE, and THRESHOLD is the deviation allowed

```
#include <stdio.h>
#define THRESHOLD 3

#define DATA 32, 51, 62, 66, 71, 83
#define DATA_SIZE 6
void main()
{
    int data[]={DATA}; int size = DATA_SIZE;
    int skip = 0, diffs, curDif, maxDif, lastItem, item, dif, maxPos;
    int maxDiffs = 10000, location, newPosition, newValue;
    for(skip = 0; skip < size; skip++)
    {
      diffs = 0;
      curDif = 0;
      maxDif = 0;
      maxPos = -1;
      lastItem = (skip == 0);
      for(item = lastItem+1; item < size; item++)
      {
        if(item == skip)continue;
        dif = data[item]-data[lastItem];
        if(abs(dif - curDif) > THRESHOLD)
        {
          curDif = dif;
          diffs++;
          if(curDif > maxDif)
          {
            maxDif = curDif;
            maxPos = item;
          }
        }
        lastItem = item;
      }

      if(diffs < maxDiffs)
      {
          maxDiffs = diffs;
          location = skip;
          newPosition = maxPos;
          newValue = data[maxPos-1]+(maxDif>>1);
      }
    }
    printf("Found... \nindex %d\nValue: %d\nGoes in:%d\nNew value:%d\n", location, data[location], newPosition, newValue);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I experimented with a lot of different approaches, this is what I ended up with. The basic idea is to assign good, valid values to the array of expected values. Values that could not be assigned get fixed by using the missing expected values instead.

Given is a list of actual data `peaks`.

Build a list of expected data

```
var expected = Enumerable
    // 19 is the known number of values
    .Range (0, 19)
    // simply interpolate over the actual data
    .Select (x => peaks.First () + x * (peaks.Last () - peaks.First ()) / 18)
    .ToList ();
```

Build a matrix of the distances of all points

```
var distances = expected.SelectMany (dst => peaks.Select (src => new {
    Expected = dst,
    Original = src,
    Distance = Math.Abs (dst - src)
}));
```

Repeat

```
for (;;)
{
```

Select the best distance

```
var best = distances
    // ignore really bad values
    .Where (x => x.Distance < dAvgAll * 0.3)
    .OrderBy (x => x.Distance).FirstOrDefault ();
```

If no good assignation was found, quit

```
if (best == null) {
    break;
}
```

Else, store the match

```
expected.Remove (best.Expected);
peaks.Remove (best.Original);

}
```

All valid entries in our source have been identified and removed. We simply use the left-over values in the expected set and ignore the left-over original values to finish our final data set.

Other attempted approaches, including a version adapted from gusbro's, worked less well and often displayed bad behavior for me.

Comment: I wont accept this as an answer for a few day because the explained approach is still quite naive; fat chance there's a better, more sophisticated solution that I would love to hear about.

Answer (score 0):

I will try to outline an algorithm (I don't know if it would give a correct result for every input sequence, therefor think of it as an idea):

Input for the algorithm is the ordered sequence `R`. For Example { 32, 51, 62, 66, 71, 83 }

1. Find distance `d` between points. I'm thinking of:

   - Sort the differences between the elements and take the median.
     Sorted differences = { 4, 5, 11, 12, 19 } --> Median = 11
   - Or calculate the mean value of the differences.
     Mean Value = 10.2 --> Rounded Mean Value = 10
2. Build the mean value `m` of the elements of `R`.
   In our example (32 + 51 + 62 + 66 + 71 + 83) / 6 = 30.2
   Rounded = 30
3. Build a comparative squence `S` where the first element `S_0` has the value
   `m - (n / 2) * d` (where `n` is the number of elements) and any further element `S_i` has the value `S_1 + i * d`.
   In our example `S` = { 30, 40, 50, 60, 70, 80 }
4. Because the elements in the input sequence could have moved to another position,
   build every permutation of `R`
5. Find the permutation where the number of outliers is minimal (outlier is element, where element difference is greater `0.3 * d`

```
                     S = { 30, 40, 50, 60, 70, 80 } 
    permutation x of R = { 32, 51, 62, 66, 71, 83 } three outliers
    permutation y of R = { 32, 66, 51, 62, 71, 83 } one outlier
    permutation z of R = ...
```

The result of the algorithm in this example would be permutation y and with it the correct position of the element 66 is found.

Comment: I'm not sure, doesn't this boil down to the same idea as explain in my answer?

Comment: @mafutrct: I'm not quite sure if I really understood your idea as a whole, and how you know to which position the wrong values should be moved in the final data set. Similarities I can see are the 30% avg. distance for finding outliers (I took this number because of your answer to my comment) and building a comparative sequence. What I can say is, that I first wrote my answer before I really tried (today) to understand yours (I'm not familar with the syntax).

Comment: The target position would be the position that is missing if the input data were flawless. In the OP that means the missing point at 42 with the standard distance (roughly 10) to 32 and 51.